# proof that the operator of integral equation is a contraction

Tags: uniform-convergence, contraction-operator, contraction-mapping

The part I am reading is similar to the following questions, so if you are not familiar with integral operator and contraction, you could refer to them.

[Show integral operator is contraction mapping](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2488194/show-integral-operator-is-contraction-mapping)

[Reiterate Volterra integral operator is a contraction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052899/reiterate-volterra-integral-operator-is-a-contraction)

I am reading a part about this.

> $h(x),K(x,t)$ are continuous functions on $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]^2$. $|K(x,t)| \le B$. $T[f](x) = \int_0^x K(x,t) f(t)dt+h(x)$. Show that $T$ is a contraction mapping.

The proof:

> define a metric: $M$ is a positive real number,
> $$d_M(f,g)=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)| e^{-Mx}
> $$
> we can show that $d(T[f],T[g])<B/Md(f,g)$.
> Then we can show that, if $M>B$, the map $T$ is a contraction on $(C([0,1]),d_M)$ where $C([0,1])$ is the space of all continuous functions whose domain is $[0,1]$.

The book is written in this way. I have typed everything. If it is confusing to you, I could not do anything about it because I am confused. I understand that this is a way to construct a $c\in [0,1)$ to make it satisfies the definition of a contraction.

Assume that everything written in the book is clear to you, my question is I am not sure how to use the $e^{-Mx}$, meaning how to link it with $B/M$.
I am also confused whether the metric $d_M$ preserve metric $d$, meaning if $T$ is a contraction on $d_M$ metric, then it is definitely a contraction on $d$ metric, or the other way around, or they are equivalent.

Comment: Are you asking how to show $d(T[f], T[g])\le B/M d(f, g)$?

Comment: I am confusing about what should  I ask, because I am not sure whether this inequality should be repect to $d_M$ or d, but it is written in this way in the book. Anyway, I think the goal should be to prove that T is a contraction mapping on traditional metric $d(f,g)=sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f-g|$.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, $T$ is not a contraction mapping on $(C[0,1], d)$. For example, if $h(x)=0$ and $K(x, y) = 1$. Then

$$ T[f](x) = \int_0^x f(s)ds.$$
If $f(x) = c_0$, $g(x) = c_1$ (that is, $f, g$ are constant functions). Then

$$ d (T[f], T[g])= d(c_0 x, c_1 x) = |c_1 - c_0| = d(f, g).$$
So there is no $c\in [0,1)$ so that $d(T[f], T[g]) \le c d(f, g)$ for all $f, g\in C([0, 1])$.

What you can show is that $T$ is a contraction on $C([0,1], d_M)$ when $M>B$. Indeed, for any $f, g\in C([0,1])$,

\begin{align}
d_M (T[f], T[g]) &= \sup_{x\in [0,1]} e^{-Mx} \left| \int_0^xK(x, t) (f(t)-g(t)) dt\right| \\
&\le B\sup_{x\in [0,1]} e^{-Mx}\int_0^x |f(t)-g(t)| dt \\
&=B\sup_{x\in [0,1]} e^{-Mx}\int_0^x e^{Mt} e^{-Mt}|f(t)-g(t)| dt \\
&\le B d_M (f, g) \sup_{x\in [0,1]} e^{-Mx}\int_0^x e^{Mt} dt \\
&=\frac BM d_M (f, g) \sup_{x\in [0,1]} e^{-Mx}(e^{Mx}-1) dt\\
&\leq\frac BM d_M (f, g) .
\end{align}

Of course, the above calculation also answers your questions: that $T$ is a contraction with respect to $d_M$ does not mean that it is a contraction with respect to $d$. But once you show that $T$ is a contraction with respect to some complete metric, you can use the contraction mapping theorem to conclude that $T$ has a fixed point.

Comment: This makes sense. I tried to get the inequality written in the book and failed afte rmultiple attempts, but I am not sure if it should be $d_M$ instead. Thank you!